# python requirements.txt, individual lines to a target

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

I'd like to move these lines to my requirements.txt, I couldn't find a way...

```
pip install ExistingLibFromPypi==10.0.0.1 --target= /Users/myuser/Documents/github/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyU4V_versions/
pip install ExistingLibFromPypi==9.0.0.1 --target= /Users/myuser/Documents/github/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyU4V_versions/
```

the reason is that there's no parity amongst the 2 versions, so I need them both installed, there's no way around it.
I am creating a wrapper that automatically chooses the appropriate one.

Ideally -since I am not the only user/installer- I'd like to have those on requirements.txt, but am not sure if there's a way to achieve that: simply replacing the line

`ExistingLibFromPypi==10.0.0.1`

with
`ExistingLibFromPypi==10.0.0.1 --target= /Users/myuser/Documents/github/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyU4V_versions/`

does not work (target seems to be an invalid flag).

I know in the worst case I can still install those manually after the requirements.txt, but ideally I'd like to have them included in the file.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through the requirements.txt file structure here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/ and it seems we cannot use `--target` flag.
For your problem, you can try writing a bash script for running those commands in addition to installing packages from requirements.txt